# Configuring BGP using Azure portal

Tags: azure, azureportal, bgp

Does Azure web portal support configuration of BGP on VPN gateways? All online documentation seems to contain steps using powershell. But powershell doesn't work with linux machine. Am I correct? 
So, does only way to conifgure BGP on VPN gateways on azure is via powershell commands on windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure BGP via the Portal.

You have two other options for Linux / CLI you could run the required PowerShell commands in Azure Automation, you could write the script there and then call that from Linux.

Alternatively you could create a template which will also let you specify BGP, have a look at this one for details - https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-site-to-site-vpn-create

Comment: Thanks for the response but I ended up creating a VM in azure with windows OS and installed azure powershell there. Though, I have another question, it seems like BgpPeeringAddress address is automatically assigned by azure (which is second last from CIDR block defined for GatewaySubnet). Can we change this to use link local address?